# No input while using Xorg in (L)Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xorg, lubuntu, arm, input

I can't get any input device to work while Xorg is running on Ubuntu 14.04 (also tried 12.04). The system is running on ARM (armhf) device. The USB keyboard and USB mouse works perfectly fine in text mode but when Xorg starts, nothing works anymore. When I kill Xorg using a serial console then, in text mode, everything works again.

I've tried to modify xorg.conf using recipes I found online but nothing helps. Can anyone give me some advice how to fix this?

Here is what Xorg.log says:

```
[   527.894]
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[   527.905] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   527.909] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-58-highbank armv7l Ubuntu
[   527.913] Current Operating System: Linux linaro-nano 3.17.4 #3 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 3 16:19:08 CET 2014 armv7l
[   527.913] Kernel command line: console=tty0 console=ttyS0,57600 root=/dev/sdb1 rw rootwait mem=992M
[   527.921] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:41:53PM
[   527.925] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[   527.929] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[   527.937]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   527.937] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   527.956] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Dec  3 15:30:35 2014
[   527.961] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   527.962] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   527.962] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   527.962] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   527.962] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   527.963] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[   527.963] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   527.963] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   527.963] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   527.964] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   527.964]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   527.964] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   527.964]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   527.964] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
[   527.964]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   527.964] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   527.964]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   527.964] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
        built-ins
[   527.964] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   527.964] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   527.964] (II) Loader magic: 0xb6fe8f18
[   527.964] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   527.964]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   527.964]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[   527.964]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[   527.964]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[   527.969] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[   527.974] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[   527.979] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[   527.984] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[   527.989] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[   527.996] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   528.001] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[   528.006] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[   528.011] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[   528.016] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[   528.021] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[   528.026] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[   528.031] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[   528.036] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[   528.041] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[   528.045] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[   528.050] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   528.055] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   528.060] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[   528.065] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[   528.070] Initializing built-in extension Present
[   528.075] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[   528.079] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[   528.084] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[   528.089] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   528.094] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[   528.098] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   528.103] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[   528.107] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[   528.111] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[   528.111] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   528.113] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   528.126] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   528.126]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   528.126]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[   528.126] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   528.131] Loading extension GLX
[   528.131] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   528.131] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   528.131] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   528.131] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   528.132] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   528.133] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   528.133]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[   528.133]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   528.133]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   528.133] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   528.134] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   528.134] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   528.134]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[   528.134]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   528.134]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   528.134] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   528.134] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   528.134] (--) using VT number 8

[   528.158] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   528.158] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   528.158] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   528.158] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   528.158] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   528.159] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   528.160] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   528.160]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[   528.160]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[   528.160] (II) FBDEV(0): using default device
[   528.160] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[   528.160] (II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   528.160] (==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   528.160] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[   528.160] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   528.160] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   528.160] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: simple (video memory: 4098kB)
[   528.160] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[   528.160] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[   528.161] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1366x768 (pitch 1366)
[   528.161] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current"
[   528.161] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   528.161] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   528.161] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   528.161] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[   528.162] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   528.162]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   528.162]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   528.162] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[   528.162] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[   528.162] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[   528.162] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[   528.163] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   528.163]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.1.0
[   528.163]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   528.163] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[   528.163] (II) Unloading modesetting
[   528.163] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   528.164] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   528.164] (WW) FBDEV(0): FBIOPAN_DISPLAY: Invalid argument
[   528.164] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
[   528.165] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[   528.166] (==) RandR enabled
[   528.201] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   528.205] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[   528.205] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[   528.227] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[   528.227] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[   528.331] (II) XKB: generating xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   528.478] (II) XKB: Reusing cached keymap
[   528.487] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/input/event0 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.487] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/input/mouse0 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.488] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/input/event1 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.489] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/input/event2 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.489] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyS0 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.489] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyS1 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.489] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/input/mice without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.490] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/console without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.490] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptmx without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.490] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp0 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.490] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp1 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.491] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp2 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.491] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp3 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.491] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp4 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.491] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp5 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.492] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp6 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.492] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp7 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.492] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp8 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.492] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptyp9 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.492] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptypa without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.493] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptypb without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.493] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptypc without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.493] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptypd without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.493] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptype without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.494] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ptypf without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.494] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.494] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty0 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.494] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty1 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.495] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty10 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.495] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty11 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.495] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty12 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.495] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty13 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.496] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty14 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.496] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty15 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.496] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty16 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.496] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty17 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.496] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty18 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.497] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty19 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.497] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty2 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.497] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty20 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.497] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty21 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.498] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty22 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.498] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty23 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.498] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty24 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.498] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty25 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.498] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty26 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.499] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty27 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.499] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty28 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.499] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty29 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.499] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty3 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.499] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty30 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.500] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty31 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.500] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty32 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.500] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty33 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.500] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty34 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.501] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty35 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.501] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty36 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.501] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty37 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.501] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty38 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.502] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty39 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.502] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty4 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.502] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty40 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.502] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty41 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.502] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty42 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.503] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty43 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.503] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty44 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.503] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty45 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.503] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty46 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.503] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty47 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.504] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty48 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.504] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty49 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.504] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty5 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.504] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty50 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.505] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty51 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.505] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty52 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.505] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty53 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.505] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty54 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.506] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty55 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.506] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty56 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.506] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty57 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.506] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty58 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.506] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty59 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.507] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty6 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.507] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty60 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.507] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty61 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.507] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty62 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.508] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty63 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.508] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty7 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.508] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty8 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.508] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/tty9 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.509] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp0 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.509] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp1 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.509] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp2 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.509] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp3 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.510] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp4 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.510] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp5 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.510] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp6 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.510] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp7 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.511] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp8 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.511] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttyp9 without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.511] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttypa without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.511] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttypb without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.512] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttypc without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.512] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttypd without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.512] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttype without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.512] (II) config/udev: ignoring device /dev/ttypf without property ID_INPUT set
[   528.513] (EE) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument
[   531.342] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   538.895] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was causing the problem. udev had some weird problems because of kernel misconfiguration. File systems -> Inotify support for userspace (whatever it is) option needs to be checked. After kernel recompilation everything started to work.